# Suggestion for a posting 'health indicator'

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, post-ban

Older posts never 'time out' or even reduce in weight in how they are considered by the post ban.  I believe my account is now teetering on the edge of being blocked. I honestly have no idea which side of this fence I am on. The fact that the fence to me feels very much like a moisture repellent membrane, in that you can pass one way through it but not easily go back, makes me extremely reticent about posting.

The other day, for instance, I had an extremely complex problem that I believed to be a good fit for SO, but I daren't post it because it would have taken me a long time to put together a good question complete with example code and I didn't want to expend that effort only to be told that my posting privileges have been revoked. So, I had the idea that it would be extremely useful to have some kind of visual indication on my account about whether or not I can currently post. This could be an icon or maybe a 'Test Post' button.

Better still would be some kind of dynamic indication, moving through green, amber and red perhaps, so that people in my position could do our best to avoid a block before it is too late.

Incidentally, I perhaps should add that I have discussed this issue with perhaps twenty people on other forums, and not one of them was aware of the strictness of the SO algorithm.

Comment: Doing so would allow you to reverse engineer the ban algorithm.  Since SO doesn't want people to know how exactly it works this would defeat that.

Comment: SO intentionally *doesn't* provide this information precisely because they *do* want people to be hesitant about asking questions.  We *want* people to only ask quesitons when they're able to really take the time to do their research, craft a well formulated question, and to be able to be confident that it's a good question.  We don't *want* people just throwing together a half-baked question because they can see they're not in immediate danger of hitting a question ban.  That you're very hesitant to ask questions and will only do so when you're sure you have a good one *is the goal here*.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to challenge here is that "I don't want to work on writing a good question in case I can't post". Honestly, I found that "writing a good SO post" is VERY similar to "troubleshooting my own issue", so this isn't SO bad. If you write a well written, concise, well explained post, then good, you are that much closer to finding your own solution. If you hit "post" then can't post... keep it as a draft. It's still a good question, one you may want to ask at the 6 months mark

Comment: "it would have taken me a long time to put together a good question complete with example code" that's actually a good thing.  I've asked many questions over my time here, but I've started asking many MANY more that I found my answer while taking the necessary steps to prepare to ask.  I've created minimal prototypes that showed me the exact error of my ways, I've done research to back up things I was about to claim only to find out my base assumptions were wrong.  *This is a good thing!*

Comment: For what it's worth, you are supposed to get a warning before the actual ban.

Comment: I am happy to put in the effort to construct a good question but that would have taken time away from solving the original problem, since all I would have been doing is copying and pasting code from one solution to another.  (Admittedly, this may have contributed something to investigating the problem but was certainly not the best use of my time).  I also wish to repeat and underline that my account is on the edge of being blocked for posts that are knocking on a decade old.  Can someone please tell me how I can ever get an up-vote on one of these?  The negative score on here says it all.

Comment: 'll I would have been doing is copying and pasting code from one solution to another.' - well creating such an MCVE is the price you must pay if you want free help on SO.  Assuming you have been duly diligent and already spent some time with your debugger/logger, you should have been able to narrow down the problem area and come up with a reasonable code example for posting...

Comment: @Patrick A lot more needs to go into a question than just copying over code, including narrowing the scope of the problem to as small an area as possible, constructing a succinct yet accurate summary of the problem, a brief description of what you attempted to do to resolve that problem, and why (specifically) it isn't working.  You'll want to spend time editing the question to remove unnecessary information, ensure all needed information is there, make sure it's clear, well formatted, etc.  And that's not even getting into doing the research before you ask the question.

Comment: I did put a lot of work into a recent question and have managed a vote of 12, so maybe my posting privilege has recovered, but how can I tell? My original question remains though: please can someone explain the logic of having no time-out? There is no way my old questions will ever get + votes. Also, this topic posted here is a fair question and yet is being down-voted. You may disagree with me but does that make my question a bad one? If this were the main forum, I'd probably now be banned for life. I'd get less for driving into a child while drunk.

Comment: @Patrick you've posted "feature-request" and votes on them are explicitly for/against the request and rarely about quality of the post itself (http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), same applies to all other types of posts to lesser degree even if rules say otherwise.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 19):

I have mixed feelings about this.

> I had an extremely complex problem that I believed to be a good fit for SO, but I daren't post it because it would have taken me a long time to put together a good question complete with example code and I didn't want to expend that effort only to be told that my posting privileges have been revoked.

On one hand, it's good that you know you need to put in some effort to post a good question complete with example code. On the other hand, it's a little bit bothersome that you don't want to expend that effort. Not wanting to expend that effort is what gets you teetering on the edge of a post ban to begin with.

If people know that they're safe, many simply won't put in any effort at all. So knowing where you stand might be helpful to you, but in the majority of cases I think it would be harmful to the community. You should take the time to write up that question and try to post it. If you're not banned, great. If you are, save it in a file for later, and come back and try to improve some of your earlier posts to try and get out of the ban.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to explain your take on this, Bill.  However, I still cannot believe there is any realistic way that I can improve the really old posts that got me in trouble in the first place. I feel like an ignorant, inconsiderate freeloader, but, honestly, if you knew me, you would find I am not like that at all.  I have always valued the help I get in forums, and I hate that I have reluctantly formed this negative view of SO.  I am looking to make amends for my old, poor posts, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Patrick Your downvoted/deleted posts aren't the only ones you can improve to help raise your overall standing. All of your questions count. Improving some of your better questions will help a little. (Remove signatures, taglines, and needless preambles. Add tags, details, code examples, links to references where you can. Answer any questions that you've found a solution for. Anything really to improve *any* of your questions will help.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Bill.